# Why is my paused readable stream not staying paused?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, stream, pipe, pause

My goal: in Node.js, stream a large-ish JSON (144mb) via fetch, parse it into items, then save each item to my Parse Platform server.  I only want to stream in a chunk after the previous chunk has been parsed and successfully saved.  I'm finding that the below code does not truly pause the stream until the previous "await newObject.save();" line completes.

There is a database I need to update every 56 days.  I'm limited to 30 reqs/second by cloud server. Some of the individual objects are largish, meaning I may have more than 30 at a time in the process of saving, so some of them get rejected.

```
  function schmoo(url){
  let count = 0;
  let downloadStart = Date.now();
  console.log("download starting at: ", downloadStart);
  fetch(url)
    .then(response =>  {
      const reader = response.body;
      reader.pipe(JSONStream.parse('features.*'))
          .on('data', async function (feature) {
            reader.pause();
            try{
                  count++;
                  await sleep(numberOfMilliseconds);
                  if(shouldAdd(feature)){
                          if(feature.geometry.type == "Polygon"){
                              let newObject = processFeature(feature, feature.geometry.coordinates[0]);
                              await newObject.save();
                          }else if (feature.geometry.type == "MultiPolygon"){
                              let i = 0;
                              for(i = 0; i < feature.geometry.coordinates.length; i++){
                                  let el = feature.geometry.coordinates[i];
                                  let newObject = processFeature(feature, el[0]);
                                  await newObject.save();
                              }
                              console.log("found multipolygon");
                            }else {
                              console.log("not a polygon or multipolygon")
                              }
                    }
              } catch(error){
                  console.log(error);
                }
              reader.resume();
              })

          .on('error', function (err) {
            throw err;
          })
          .on('end', function (){
            console.log("parsed through", count, "items finished after", Date.now()-start);
          });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a NodeJS stream is a good fit for the problem description. The stream library's backpressure will force each chunk of work to be processed sequentially.

The example provided by the OP combine using the `data` event in flowing mode with an async event handler. This tells NodeJS to execute the registered event handler each time a new piece of data / JSON is available in the pipe. However, NodeJS will not automatically await the async function. Thus, the async event handler is executed sequentially for each chunk, but it won't wait for the previous chunks to have finished processing before moving on to the next chunk.

NodeJS (< v13) requires the implementer to provide a `stream.Writable` when combining async handling of stream chunks with backpressure. The Writable class has a `callback` function that indicate when each chunk have completed processing:

```js
import stream from "stream";
import util from "util";

let downloadStart = Date.now();

fetch(url)
  .then(response =>  {
const reader = response.body;

return util
  .promisify(stream.pipeline)(
    reader, 
    new stream.Writable({
      write: (feature, encoding, callback) => {
        try {
          await sleep(numberOfMilliseconds);
          if(shouldAdd(feature)){
            // do work
          }
          callback();
        }
        catch(error){
          callback(error);
        }
      }
    })
  )
  .then(()=>{
    console.log("parsed through", count, "items finished after", Date.now()-start);
  })
  });
```

If you're working with NodeJS v13+ you may use an async iterator instead of a Writable, which tend to make this use case more concise:

```js
import stream from "stream";
import util from "util";

let downloadStart = Date.now();

fetch(url)
  .then(response =>  {
    const reader = response.body;

    return util
      .promisify(stream.pipeline)(reader, async (source) => {
        for await (const feature of source){
          await sleep(numberOfMilliseconds);
          if(shouldAdd(feature)){
            // do work
          }
        }
      })
      .then(()=>{
        console.log("parsed through", count, "items finished after", Date.now()-start);
      })
  });
```